# Getting progress reports from a layered worker class?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, progress

I have a layered worker class that I'm trying to get progress reports from.  What I have looks something like this:

```
public class Form1
{
    private void Start_Click()
    {
        Controller controller = new Controller();

        controller.RunProcess();
    }
}

public class Controller
{
    public void RunProcess()
    {
        Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoEverything));
        newThread.Start();
    }

    private void DoEverything()
    {
        // Commencing operation...
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();

        class1.DoStuff();

        Class2 class2 = new Class2();

        class2.DoMoreStuff();
    }

}

public class Class1
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // Doing stuff
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Want to report progress here
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public void DoMoreStuff()
    {
        // Doing more stuff
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Want to report progress here as well
    }
}
```

I've used the BackgroundWorker class before, but I think I need something a bit more free form for something like this. I think I could use a delegate/event solution, but I'm not sure how to apply it here. Let's say I've got a few labels or something on Form1 that I want to be able to update with class1 and class2's progress, what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using events is the most straightforward solution.  When you subscribe to the event from the main thread, the handler should check the `Control.IsInvokeRequired` to know whether it must call itself again through `Invoke(...)` to get the message passed to the right thread.

Answer (score 1):

John is correct.  You want to utilize events and for that you'll need to use a delegate or delegates. This might give you some ideas.

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to block the processing threads during notification, you can use [`Control.BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx) for fire & forget behavior.

To decrease the number of calls and update progress on a *regular* interval, you may want to encapsulate the states of different operations in classes.
This way you can just write states to e.g. volatile fields - of presumably another, aggregate-state class - and use a timer on the GUI thread to re-read state and refresh labels accordingly.